# Select multiple rows with multiple matching id(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to query data to display multiple rows with multiple selector?

like:

```
SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `book`.id = 1 AND `book`.id = 2;
```

table:

```
id name
1  book1
2  book2
3  book3
4  book4
```

I dun suppose looping for each id is favourable.

Comment: Assuming you are using backticks to escape identifiers, I am tagging this question with `mysql` RDBMS tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution you have, but you made an error. An id cannot be both `1` and `2`, so you need to use `OR` to return those rows that are either `1` or `2`.

```
SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `book`.id = 1 OR `book`.id = 2;
```

A slightly simpler notation would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `book`.id in (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, yeah, you can use `in`, but this is the same as multiple `or`, not `and` – one value can't be equal to the two unequal values at once:

```
select *
from `book`
where `book`.id in(1, 2)
```